# Odds of two specific Hold'Em hands and an exact board?

Tags: statistics, poker

The goal is to solve the probability of a Texas Holdem hand occurring where at the river one player has quad $9$s and the other player has exactly a $9$-high straight flush.

(For non poker players - in holdem each player has $2$ cards and the board has 5 cards - players make the best hand of $5$ by any combination using their hole cards and the board)

This requires that:

- (A) Player 1 holds 2 nines but not the nine of diamonds
- (B) Player 2 holds any two of the $5,6,7$ and $8$ of diamonds
- (C) The board by the river contains the other two diamonds not held by player 2 AND must not have the 10 of diamonds on the board, plus must have the last 9.

I know the final probability is A * B * C

A = 3/52 * 2/51

B = 4/50 * 3/49 (since we know A we can lower the card count right?)

How do we solve C?

I think it's something like: (4/48 + 3/47 + 2/46 + 1/45 + 1/44) - (odds of 10d) but ... I'm not sure if that math is right or how to calculate the odds of just the 10d.

(Edit - forgot the 4th 9 needed to be on the board)

Comment: A, B, and C are not independent.

Comment: That's why for B I used 50 and 49 cards, not 52 and 51 cards...  and similar for C.  Is that what you're getting at or am I missing you? @Gaffney

Comment: Knowing the probabilities in hold em' only makes the game more frustrating.  When the "fish" with 2 outs gets there on the river, you want to bang your head on the table.

Comment: True.  However, the reason behind this question has nothing to do with fish.  This is actually a requirement for the only bad-beat jackpot offered by a local card-room.  I'm curious about the precise odds, because I'd like to illustrate to the room just how moronic it is to think that this has any chance of bringing in players to the room in hopes of hitting it.

Comment: My guess for the probability of $C$ given $A$ and $B$ is $\frac{2}{48}\cdot\frac{1}{47}\cdot\frac{1}{46}\cdot\left(1-\frac{2}{44}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{l}5\\3\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Ok.  Why?  How did you arrive at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances for $C$ are $43/{48\choose 5}=43*120/(44*45*46*47*48)$  There are $48\choose5$ possible tables.  It needs the other two diamonds, the other two nines, and one other card which is not the ten.  So there are 43 possible tables that work.
Overall, chances of it happening with diamonds is 43/154521166800; happening at all is 43/38630291700, slightly better than one in a billion.  Double that if player 1 and player 2 can swap places.

Comment: How do you arrive at 43, and where does the *120 come from?

Comment: After the nines and the other diamonds, there are 44 cards left.  The fifth slot is one of those, but not the ten of diamonds.  ${48\choose 5}=48*47*46*45*44/(5*4*3*2*1)$ is the number of possible tables; success requires two specific diamonds, two specific nines and one of 43 other cards.

Comment: Ok, I get the 48.  Where'd the * 120 come from?

Comment: 120=5*4*3*2*1, so ${48\choose 5}=48*47*46*45*44/120$ and $43/{48\choose5}=43*120/(48*47*46*45*44)$

Comment: Ah of course - duh.  Thanks!

Comment: I get a much different number for (48/5) = 1712304.